# how to change the value of row index(DT_RowIndex) in yajra datatables

Tags: laravel, datatable, laravel-8, yajra-datatable

By default `addIndexColumn()` in yajra is auto increment.
but I want to create my own index.
maybe like this

```
->addIndexColumn(function ($row) {
                return $row->partCode;
            })
```

but the code above doesn't work.

Answer (score 0):

Last night I faced the same problem, but could not solve using

```
->addIndexCoulumn(something)
```

I also tried

```
 ->setRowId('id')
```

This was in the yajra docs.
Then just removed the index column and used

```
 ->addColumn(something...)
```

It showed, but not sure if is it right or not